# Image from database is not displaying on webpage

Tags: php, html, css, sql

so I have this blog that I am creating, but I am having issues with displaying an image from a database to the page itself. It only comes up with a broken image. The data does appear in the database however. It just doesn't display on the page.

Here is the image.php code (used to display the text and images):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
//connect to database

//Name the variables
$host= "localhost";
//Localhost is the name of the computer that USBWebser has been loaded on
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$database = "blog";

$dbh=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());

//if cannot connect to database display error message
if(!$dbh)
{
echo mysql_error();
}

mysql_select_db("$database");

//get the id number of the row that the photo is located in and place it in $ano
$ano=$_GET['postID'];

//select the data and type for the photo identified by id
$sql="SELECT photo, phototype FROM blog where postID='$ano'";

//check if sql query can be executed
$r=mysql_query($sql, $dbh);

//if sql query can be executed
if($r)
{

//get the data from the query
$row=mysql_fetch_array($r);

//set the header information so that an image can be displayed
$type="Content-type: image/png" .$row['phototype'];
header($type);

//display the image
echo $row['photo'];
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Here is the code for the main_menu.php (where I would like the image to appear)

```
<?PHP
//Name the variables
$host= "localhost";
//Localhost is the name of the computer that USBWebser has been loaded on
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$database = "blog";

$mysqli=new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

//Connect to Header
include "header.php";
?>
<?php
//Select fields from the posts table
$sql="SELECT postID, title, date, contents, rating, photo, phototype FROM posts";
//Place the data into a variable named $result
$result= $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows>0){

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<br><table border="1" bordercolor="25dae3" width="53%"><th><font color="white">Title</th><th><font color="white">Date</th><th><font color="white">Contents</th><th><font color="white">Image</th><th><font color="white">Rating</th>
<tr><td width = "100" align="center"><font color="white">
<?php 
echo $row["title"];
?>
</td>
<br><td width="100" align="center"><font color="white">
<?php
echo $row["date"];
?>
</td>
<br><td width="300" align="center"><font color="white">
<?php
echo $row["contents"];
?>
</td>
<br><td width="300" align="center"><font color="white">
<img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>;
</td>
<br><td width="100" align="center"><font color="white">
<?php
echo $row["rating"];
?>
</td></tr></font>
<?php
}
} else {
    //Display message that no data was present
    echo "0 results";
}
//Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The add_post.php

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<?php
//Name the variables
$host = "localhost";
//Localhost is the name of the computer that USBWebserver has been loaded on 
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$database = "blog";

$mysqli=new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

//Get variables from the form 
$new_post_title=$_POST["newtitle"];
$new_post_date=$_POST["newdate"];
$new_post_contents=$_POST["newcontents"];
$new_post_rating=$_POST["newrating"];
$photo=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]));
$imagesize=getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]); 

//mime returns the image time eg. image/jpeg
$imagetype=$imagesize['mime'];

//Enable sql to read quotation marks within sentences
$new_post_title=addslashes($new_post_title);
$new_post_date=addslashes($new_post_date);
$new_post_contents=addslashes($new_post_contents);
$new_post_rating=addslashes($new_post_rating);

//Enter the new information into the posts table 
$sql="INSERT INTO posts(postID, title, date, contents, rating, photo, phototype) VALUES (Null, '$new_post_title', '$new_post_date', '$new_post_contents', '$new_post_rating', '$photo', '$imagetype')"; 

//Run the query 
$result=$mysqli->query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

if ($result) {

header ('location:main_menu.php');
}

else {
echo mysql_error();
}
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

And the form to submit a post to the blog (add_new_post.php)

```
<HTML>
<style>
form {
    border-opacity: 1.0 ;
    display: incline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=date]:focus {
width: 50%;
height: 20%;     
border: 3px solid #00ffff;   
}

body {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 50px; 
 }

</style>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY><font color="white">
<br><br><br><H1 text-align="center">Add a New Post</H1>
<?php 
//Connect To Header Page
include "header1.php";

//Connect To Database
include "dbconnect.php";
?>
<br>
<br>
<!-- <HR> Tag inserts a horizonal line across the page (horizontal rule)-->
<!-- <Form> Tag indicates that a form will be created -->
<!-- action indicates the file used to process the input when the submit button is pressed-->
<form enctype= "multipart/form-data" action="add_post.php" method = "POST">
Title: <br>
<!-- <input type> Tag indicates the type of input expected eg. text. Name = indicates the name given to the input-->
<input type="text" name="newtitle"><br>
Date: <br>
<input type="date" name="newdate"><br>
Contents: <br>
<input type="text" name="newcontents"><br>
Rating: <br>
<input type="text" name="newrating"><br>
Please Browse to where the photo is located:<br> 
<input type = file name = "photo"><br>
<br>
<!-- Value indicates the text to be displayed. In this case, displayed on the button -->
<input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any assistance on this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: stop using mysql-*

Comment: <?php
echo"<img src="$row['photo']" width=300 height=300/>"; 
?>

Comment: @nogad wish it was that simple, but it's required for this task

Comment: @iCoders Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in \main_menu.php on line 56

Comment: @Thomas.you are using wrong src in image

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>";

Comment: @nogad said to use mysqli instead of mysql in your code because mysql is now depreciated

Comment: how is using a depricated, dangerous, API "required"?

Comment: @nogad, final IPT assignment at school

Comment: @Thomas use <img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>";.

Comment: tell you "school" that they are teaching dangerous code. dont expect to get a job with code like that

Comment: @iCoders Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in \main_menu.php on line 56

Comment: can you show updated code

Comment: replace this <?php
echo"<img src=image.php?postID=".($row['postID'])."width=300 height=300/>"; 
?>  to <img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>";

Comment: @iCoders yeah okay, I changed it to that, but then the webpage displayed with a bunch of random characters.

Comment: @iCoders didnt work, came up with a whole bunch of random characters again

Comment: @Thomas.update error in your question

Answer (score 0):

You are using php tag wrong

```
<br><td width="300" align="center"><font color="white">
<?php
echo "<img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>";  
?>
</td>
```

instead of above code use following code

```
 <br><td width="300" align="center"><font color="white">
   <img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" width=300 height=300/>

    </td>
```